# Open Maya callBacks in Python or C++ query all callbacks in Memory

Tags: python, c++, callback, maya, maya-api

**Hello, I'm wondering if there is a way to query all **User Created** `callbacks` in **Maya**?, 
And in the same way, if I can query what objects or nodes are connected to them. I want to manage better the cleanliness in the memory at every time and not let any callback lost in memory.**

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.OpenMaya as OpenMaya
##########################################
class MayaSignals(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MayaSignals)       
        self.callback_list = []

    def setCallback(self, node):
        sel = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
        sel.add(node)
        obj = OpenMaya.MObject()
        sel.getDependNode(0, obj)       
        idx = OpenMaya.MNodeMessage.addAttributeChangedCallback(obj, self.reading_node)
        self.callback_list.append(idx)

    def removeAllCallback(self):
        for idx,itm in enumerate(self.callback_list):
            print(idx, 'removed')
            OpenMaya.MMessage.removeCallback(itm)

    def reading_node(self, msg, plug, otherplug, *clientData):
        if msg & OpenMaya.MNodeMessage.kAttributeSet:
            print ('Attribute Changed On: %s' % plug.name())
        if msg & OpenMaya.MNodeMessage.kConnectionMade:
            print('Connection Created On: %s' % plug.name()) 
        if msg & maya.OpenMaya.MNodeMessage.kConnectionBroken:
            print ("Broken Connection On: %s" % plug.name())

################################################################################################        
node = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]         #< ------ Node string type

#signal = MayaSignals()            # class to manage the callbacks
#signal.setCallback(node)
signal # # #                       # to keep the instance alive
signal.removeAllCallback()         # remove all into the array 


# ---------------------------------------------`-`---------------------------------------------- #
```

Here, I created an example where I tag an object to a callback, and print something when some conditions happen, also. add to array every callback ID to delete it later.

I just need a light, even if is in **C++** I could check on the docs about the recommendations here.

Comment: once you lose the callback's address, it's gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of doing what you want. The closest you can come is to use [MMessage::nodeCallbacks](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-SDK/cpp_ref/class_m_message.html#ace2f799217b34ba828a297c79af01115) to retrieve the callback ids registered against a specific node.

Comment: Please add a minimal explanation in the answer itself, as the link provided may happen to unavailable in the future.

Comment: this will work, this post is a little old, let's say 3 months ago, but a nodeCallbacks actually worked for me inside the workflow to maintain in some way the callbacks on the radar. thank you for sharing